# VueJS doesn't update the data in Browser, when changing the "app" parameter's value in JS Console

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, console, localhost, vue-directives

As I already mentioned in the question, below is a seemingly valid and syntactically correct VueJs example which I am running in Localhost with Windows 7 64Bit environment (Nginx configured):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="application/x-javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
        </div>
        <script type="application/x-javascript">
            var myObject = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    message: 'Hello Vue!'
                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now when I run this in Firefox Browser(version 65.0), it displays the expected text, but when I F12 open the Console and type `app.message = 'Test';` and then press Enter, it doesn't update the text in the browser, just the like the docs said it would.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `myObject.message = 'Test';`. `myObject` is the reference to the VueJS app.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that in docs they had binded the VueJs with `app` instead of `myObject` in my case, thanks man !!!